# Rails 3.0 use sanitize and simple_format from application_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When in my view, I want to render (and truncate) some paragraph with safe html tags like `p` `i` `br` etc, I use this code:

```
- @last_testimony.each do |last_testimony|
  = sanitize(simple_format(truncate(last_testimony.description, :length => 25)), :tags => %w(p i br b))
```

It renders the paragraph with html tags.

But when I pass that code to my application_helper

```
def paragraph(text, length)
  "#{sanitize(simple_format(truncate(text, :length => length)), :tags => %w(p i br b))}"
end
```

With this view

```
- @last_testimony.each do |last_testimony|
  = paragraph(last_testimony.description, 10)
```

It renders

```
< p>My paragraph < /p>
```

How to fix it? Is there a better method to render paragraphs with safe tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ways to do it:

1.

```
- @last_testimony.each do |last_testimony|
  = raw paragraph(last_testimony.description, 10)
```

2.

```
def paragraph(text, length)
  "#{sanitize(simple_format(truncate(text, :length => length)), :tags => %w(p i br b))}".html_safe
end
```